# Delete tags in custom TinyWebDB

Tags: app-inventor, tinyweb

Is it possible to delete tags in a custom TinyWebDB without having to go into the database and manually delete them?

There is no block to do so, and I tried storing the tag as an empty string, but the tag doesn't go away.

Comment: this answer https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/9W_q63-GRqM/WOhVjdNXBAAJ might help

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I will try creating a custom database using the deleteable and see how it goes.

Comment: @Taifun Works great, thank you!